# Android: Volley Requests are very very slow and usually result in TimeoutError

Tags: android, https, xmlhttprequest, android-volley

I just integrated Volley from my project and the requests are painfully slow and most of them even fail with TimeoutError. All the requests are https:// 
But the same request via Postman client finishes about 7 seconds.

I have tried the following, one by one, but NONE of them have worked:

- Set initialTimeoutMs to 0
- Increased initialTimeoutMs to 60000
- Set retry count to 0
- Increased number of threads assigned for request pool.

Could someone please help me with this?
Thanks.